# data output from database through ajax jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

how can i get the data from my database when i click each of my button's id
my controller function

```
public function ajax (){
   $resultdata = $this->Booking_model->roominfo();
   echo json_encode($resultdata);
}
```

here's my button with its data-room-id and class

`<button class="bkng bkn-room trans_200" data-room-id ="1">BOOK NOW</button>`

here's my model

```
public function roominfo() {
  //if(isset($_POST["id"]))
  //{
        $sql = "Select name, price from rooms WHERE room_id = 'id'";
        $result =  $this->db->query($sql);
        return $result->result_array();
  //}
```

my ajax jquery with its button class and data-room-id

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".bkng").on("click", function(event) {
              event.preventDefault(); 
            var id = $(this).data('room-id');
                console.log(id); 
                if(id != '') 
                {
                    $.ajax( {
                    type:"get",
                    url : "Pages/ajax",
                    data:{id:id}, 
                    success:function(data)
                    {
                        alert(data);
                        result = JSON.parse(data); 
                        $('#test1').append(result[0]['name']);
                        $("#test2").append(result[0]['price']);
                        $("#test3").append(result[0]['price']);
                        console.log(data); 
                    }
                });
            } 
            });
        });
```

it always says in the console error that  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Comment: `console.log(result)` contains name attribute?

Comment: @Jed does your query returns the `name` attribute ?

Comment: no it does not return the name attribute it cannot read the [0] and the name property i dont know what to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you get this error, because your query is not returning anything, as you might not have a room with the `id = 'id'`. Therefore JSON.parse returns this error.

so first you need to fix your model building a valid query, like:

```
function roominfo() {
    $id=$_POST["id"];
    $query=$this->db->select('name, price')
                    ->where('room_id', $id)
                    ->get('rooms');
    return ($query->num_rows())? $query->result_array():false;  
}
```

then in your ajax success, you can check for the data returned with:
`console.dir(data)` and not with alert or console.log as they will not show you the array structure

you also should check the eventuality of no data (false) was returned:

```
  type: 'POST',
  success:function(data)
    {
        console.dir(data);
        if (data){
            result = JSON.parse(data); 
            $('#test1').append(result[0]['name']);
            $("#test2").append(result[0]['price']);
        }
        else
        {
            $('#test1').append('no records found']);
        } 
    }
```

Comment: i tried what you said  but there's an error i think it doesnt read the id <p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Undefined index: id</p>
<p>Filename: models/Booking_model.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 28</p> here's the code $id = $_POST["id"];
  $query=$this->db->select('name, price')
                    ->where('room_id', $id)

Comment: I just noticed: to receive the POST variable you need to change your ajax from `type:'GET'` to `type: 'POST'`

Comment: nice sir. thank you very much it now loads the data! How change i change the data when i click the button2? for example i click button1 then it loads the name and the price of the room, if i click button2 it will show the data of the button2 and remove the data of the button1. this is my code `$("#test1").append(result[0]['name']); $("#test2").append(result[0]['price']); `

Comment: You are welcome. Please ask a new question to cover the new problem, please create a create a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and also read about [**What should I do when someone answers my question?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Thanks.

Comment: oh thanks again sir! btw can you please visit my question about my early comment? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59127282/jquery-ajax-data-query thanks sir!